# Thermalisation of a species in early universe

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology

Let us take the example of neutrino decoupling in the early universe. neutrino decouples from photons and electrons around 2.5 MeV. After that the neutrino and electron-photon plasma have a different temperature - there is no sharing of entropy between these two sectors. How are the neutrinos (i.e. 3 neutrinos * 2 spin states) in equilibrium with each other? How do the neutrinos thermalize when the neutrino-neutrino scattering has decoupled much earlier (as weak interaction had decoupled already)?

Answer (score 1):

Neutrinos already were in thermal equilibrium at the time of decoupling, ~1 sec. If we were to detect today's Cosmic Neutrino Background (CNB), it is presumed to be a blackbody spectrum with a temperature of 1.95K, today, and to be the very same neutrinos that existed at 1 sec.

Note that the CMB is at a higher temperature, because the electron-positron annihilation (at ~10 sec) dumped energy into photons then. (Incidentally, those very photons created at 10 sec are the ones seen in today's CMB).